# css added with addclass not working when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menubar with the following links.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li><a href="aboutus.php" onclick="changecss(1)">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="services.php" onclick="changecss(2)">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="career.php" onclick="changecss(3)">Career</a></li>
  <li><a href="contactus.php" onclick="changecss(4)">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to make current page link active in the menubar. So I am using `addclass` method..

```
$(".menu ul li a").click(function() 
{
  $(".menu ul li a").removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

All these codes resides in **header.html** page which is my header file.I am including this page using php in every other pages.

The problem is that when I click on the menubar links, the `addclass` is working but by the time the page is loaded(to the `href` page), the `addclass's` css wont work. Can anyone help to fix the problem?

Comment: It's better to do this in your `Server Side`, and add class `selected` to your related link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all.
Solved the problem.I included the **addclass** in every pages otherwise on loading it won't work.
In the **header.php** file I assigned the current page url to a variable **page** so that in any pages which includes header file, the page variable is accessible.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){`<br/> 
   if(page=="localhost/workspace/pjt/aboutus") {` <br/>
   $(".menu ul li a").removeClass('selected');` <br/>
   $(".menu ul li a#about").addClass('selected'); } });
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you use the document ready method? If not, there is your problem. The DOM is not fully loaded when you execute your jQuery code. Execute your code like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".menu ul li a").click(function() { 
        $(".menu ul li a").removeClass('selected'); 
        $(this).addClass('selected'); 
    });
});
```

...or...just execute your code in a script tag at the bottom of your page (right before the closing body tag).

As a side node:

```
$(function() {});
```

is short for

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try under document.ready like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menu ul li a").click(function() { 
        $(".menu ul li a").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected'); 
    });
     //Here defaulty add class for first link on page load like
    $(".menu ul li a:eq(0)").addClass('selected'); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do this in your Server Side code, however it's possible to do it in Client Side too.
You must get the current page address, and then, select your link based on it:

```
$(function () {
    // get the current page
    var link = window.location.href.split('/');
    page = link[link.length - 1];

    // now select the link based on the address
    $('.menu ul li a[href*="' + page + '"]').addClass('selected');
});
```